# Splitting mail headers using preg_match

Tags: php, pcre

I have to email headers and I want to extract the different data: from, subject, date, etc..

```
$mail1 = 'From: <encuestas@despegar.com>
To: 4fb661d55e409@ventas.ciudades.com
Subject: Califique nuestro servicio
Date: Sat, 19 May 2012 10:39:04 -0400
Message-ID: <3b6401cd35cd$23d08b90$0c01010a@despexds.net>
MIME-Version: 1.0';

$mail2 = 'Date: Fri, 21 Oct 2011 13:42:46 +0000 (GMT)
From: "Decolar.com" <non-reply@despegar.com>
To: 4ea15be894aca@ventas.ciudades.com
Message-ID: <2009175400.15674.1319204566275.JavaMail.root@uns02>
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Decolar.com_-_Solicita=C3=A7=C3=A3o_?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?de_compra_-_N=C3=BAmero:10603789?=
MIME-Version: 1.0';


preg_match("/Subject: (.)*(Date|Message-ID|From|To|MIME-Version):/s",$mail1,$m);        
print_r($m);
```

I'm using the code above for getting just the subject, but the result is not the expected.

For mail1 I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Subject: Califique nuestro servicio
Date: Sat, 19 May 2012 10:39:04 -0400
Message-ID: <3b6401cd35cd$23d08b90$0c01010a@despexds.net>
MIME-Version:
    [1] => 

    [2] => MIME-Version
)
```

For mail2 I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Decolar.com_-_Solicita=C3=A7=C3=A3o_?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?de_compra_-_N=C3=BAmero:10603789?=
MIME-Version:
    [1] => 

    [2] => MIME-Version
)
```

I both cases, subject is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would probably do something like:

```
function normalize_array($arr) {
    for ($res = array(), $i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i+=2) {
        $key = strtr($arr[$i],array(': '=>'','-'=>'_'));
        $res[$key] = $arr[$i+1];
    }
    return $res;
}

$mailData = normalize_array(preg_split('~([\w-]+: )~',$mail1,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
print_r($mailData);
```

which will return:

```
Array
(
    [From] => <encuestas@despegar.com>

    [To] => 4fb661d55e409@ventas.ciudades.com

    [Subject] => Califique nuestro servicio

    [Date] => Sat, 19 May 2012 10:39:04 -0400

    [Message_ID] => <3b6401cd35cd$23d08b90$0c01010a@despexds.net>

    [MIME_Version] => 1.0
)
```

Comment: This is not what I was looking for, but it is even a better solution! Thanks a lot inhan

Comment: You're welcome. You might wanna eliminate newlines in the subject field (since they can not exist) by adding `'\r\n'=>'','\n'=>'','\r'=>''` in the replacements array.

Comment: yeah, I wasn't sure if they could exist, I think they are just there because of a wrapping when I saved the email. Anyway, its a nice cleaning to do.

Answer (score 1):

Regex pattern should be:

```
/Subject: (.*)\b/
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to match exactly the text "Date", "Message",..,  not anyone. Thanks anyway for the help, I've learnt something new ;)